# How many activity diagrams should I design?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have to implement a web app and as good practice wants, I started from the very beginning with the UML. I designed the use case diagrams, but now I'm struggling to find good information about the best ways to design an activity diagram. 
I don't know how to begin... I mean, I don't know which activities I should design or how big they should be. I don't know if I should go with few big detailed activity diagrams or more smaller ones. I don't know how many details I should put inside the diagram, for instance: if there is an activity diagram which describes the activities of a user buying a product on a eCommerce, should I include inside the diagram also "*open the app*", "*go to the search items page*", "*write something inside the search bar*", "*display the search results*", "*select the desired item*", "*add the item into the cart*" activities? Or should I just put "*search an item*", "*buy the item*" activities? Hope to have made myself clear.

Comment: First of all, you should keep in mind that diagrams are not an end in itself. They should provide useful information to someone who looks at them. (This could be yourself some time later.) If you don't find a way to create such a diagram, don't waste your time forcing you to do it. It might be better to write a textual documentation of your design or just to write readable, self explaining code.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it depends. You don't need a single AD if your UC description is well formed (e.g. you use the Cockburn forms). Then of course it depends on your audience. If you have to deal with a customer for whom a system is designed you should make lots of detailed ADs so you can discuss and clarify that the UCs are well understood. If you just deal with internal developers you will get by with less details. If you outsource things you again will need more detail. So in short: see my first sentence.